# Invert the key and value of an object while the value is an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, underscore.js

I have the following:

```
var object = {
    a: ["A1"],
    b: ["B1", "B2"],
    c: ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]
};
```

And I want to convert the above to this:

```
var result = {
    A1: "a",
    B1: "b",
    B2: "b",
    C1: "c",
    C2: "c",
    C3: "c",
    C4: "c"
};
```

I am new to Javascript. Is there any effective way to do this? I can import other libraries if needed and assume the values in the array is unique. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous word. I am looking for an answer with built in functions over writing loops myself.

Comment: There is no such single built-in function. But you can wrap couple loops into your function and pretend it's built-in.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/hkp2c44g/1/

Comment: @adeneo and the same with local `object` and without shared `o`: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/hkp2c44g/2/ :-)

Comment: @zerkms Thanks. Your answer is good, why don't you answer the question but only put the comments?

Comment: @wdetac it's ugly - 2 loops is easier to deal with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var object = {
  a: ["A1"],
  b: ["B1", "B2"],
  c: ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]
};
var keys = Object.keys(object);
var obj = {};
for(var j=0,l=keys.length;j<l;j++){
  for (var i = 0; i < object[keys[j]].length; i++) {
    obj[object[keys[j]][i]] = keys[j];
  }
}
console.log(obj);
```

```js
var object = {
  a: ["A1"],
  b: ["B1", "B2"],
  c: ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]
};
var keys = Object.keys(object);
var obj = {};

for(var j=0,l=keys.length;j<l;j++){
  for (var i = 0; i < object[keys[j]].length; i++) {
    obj[object[keys[j]][i]] = keys[j];
  }
}
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `forEach` and `arrow` function (`ES6` standard)

```js
var object = { a: ["A1"], b: ["B1", "B2"], c: ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"] };

var result = {};

Object.keys(object).forEach(k =>
    object[k].forEach(a => result[a] = k));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```